# What's the difference between addon recorder and recording?

Tags: automation, rpa, g1ant

I have used both addon recording and recorder, recorder basically used for UI and recording for every application in the system but both are quite the same as I can record even UI using addon recording. Is there any major difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

G1ANT.Addon.Recorder is obsolete and will be removed in favor of G1ANT.Addon.Recording.